# Return Multiple Serial Numbers from Cisco Devices

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am parsing the show version command for a series of information.  Maybe there is any easier way, but I am trying to return all the serial numbers for devices in a stack.  Currently I am only getting back the active switches serial number.  Also I need to search through multiple areas for the serial number.  Both Processor Board ID and System Serial Number.

I have tested the following Regex strings on https://regex101.com, 
.*?^System\sSerial\sNumber\s
^System Serial Number\s([^,]+)

But in my code they do not seem to be working.  When I print my variable it is showing empty for all iterations through the For loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from getpass import getpass
import netmiko
import re

def make_connection (ip, username, password):
     return netmiko.ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', ip=ip, 
     username=username, password=password)

def get_ip (input):
     return(re.findall(r'(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3} 
     (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)', input))

def get_ips (file_name):
    #with does all the cleanup and prework of file open for you
    with open(file_name, 'r') as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            #this is probably supposed to be lineips = get_ip(line)
            #line = get_ip(line)
            lineips = get_ip(line)
        for ip in lineips:
            ips.append(ip)

def to_doc_a(file_name, varable):
    f=open(file_name, 'a')
    f.write(str(varable))
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()

def to_doc_w(file_name, varable):
    f=open(file_name, 'w', newline="\n")
    f.write(str(varable))
    f.close()

#This will be a list of the devices we want to SSH to
ips = []
#Pull the IPs.txt is a list of the IPs we want to connect to
#This function pulls those IPs out of the txt file and puts them into a 
#list
get_ips('IPs.txt')

#list where informations will be stored
#devices = []
#Results string storage
strresults = ""

#Prompt user for account info
username = input("Username: ")
password = getpass()
file_name = "results.csv"
#Clearing all the old info out of the results.csv file
to_doc_w(file_name, "")

#Make a for loop to hit all the devices, for this we will be looking at 
#the IOS it’s running
for ip in ips:
    #Connect to a device
    net_connect = make_connection(ip, username, password)
    #Run a command and set that to output
    output = net_connect.send_command('show version')

    #finding hostname in output using regular expressions
    regex_hostname = re.compile(r'(\S+)\suptime')
    hostname = regex_hostname.findall(output)

    #finding uptime in output using regular expressions
    regex_uptime = re.compile(r'\S+\suptime\sis\s(.+)')
    uptime = regex_uptime.findall(output)

    #finding version in output using regular expressions
    regex_version = re.compile(r'Cisco\sIOS\sSoftware.+Version\s([^,]+)')
    version = regex_version.findall(output)

    #finding serial in output using regular expressions
    regex_serial = re.compile(r'Processor\sboard\sID\s(\S+)')
    serial = regex_serial.findall(output)

    #finding serial in output using regular expressions
    regex_serial2 = re.compile(r'^System Serial Number\s([^,]+)')
    serial2 = regex_serial2.findall(output)
    print(serial2)

    #finding ios image in output using regular expressions
    #regex_ios = re.compile(r'System\s\image\s\file\sis\s"([^ "]+)')
    #ios = regex_ios.findall(output)

    #finding model in output using regular expressions
    regex_model = re.compile(r'[Cc]isco\s(\S+).*memory.')
    model = regex_model.findall(output)

    #append results to table [hostname,uptime,version,serial,ios,model]
    #devices.append([hostname[0], uptime[0], version[0], serial[0], 
    #model[0]])

    results = (ip, hostname, version, serial, serial2, model)
    #Store results for later, reduce calls to append file, greatly i 
    #ncrease performance
    strresults = strresults + str(results) + "\n"
    #Next we will append the output to the results file
    #to_doc_a(file_name, results)
to_doc_w(file_name, strresults)
```

No matter what Cisco device I would like this to pull the serial number and if there are multiple devices in a stack return all the serial numbers for devices in the stack.  Also it should return IP, hostname, Version of Code and Model.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the text that you are parsing with regex.

Comment: Processor board ID XXXXXXXXXXX
System Serial Number               : XXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Where the 11 X's is the serial number.

Comment: sgncs1#sh ver
Cisco IOS Software, C3550 Software (C3550-IPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.2(44)SE6, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Copyright (c) 1986-2009 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Image text-base: 0x00003000, data-base: 0x012A99FC
ROM: Bootstrap program is C3550 boot loader
sgncs1 uptime is 5 weeks, 2 days, 20 hours, 12 minutes
System image file is "flash:c3550-ipservicesk9-mz.122-44.SE6.bin"

Cisco WS-C3550-24 (PowerPC) processor (revision G0) with 65526K/8192K 
Processor board ID CHK0644W0KC
Model number: WS-C3550-24-SMI
System serial number: CHK0644W0KC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the System Serial Number, your pattern `^System Serial Number\s([^,]+)` uses an anchor to assert the start of the string, starts with uppercase `Serial Number` and is missing a colon `:` after number.

You could update your pattern where `(\S+)` captures in a group matching 1+ times a non whitespace char. In your pattern you use `[^,]+` to match not a comma, but that would also match a space or newline.

```
System serial number:\s(\S+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/54Vq9c/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cfg7Hd)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that.  I was banging my head against the wall and it was my regex causing me grief.  Especially the ^ to start.